# Cannot allocate vector in R despite being in 64-bit version

Tags: r

I am trying to do a dcast in R to generate a matrix as seen in [another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888516/how-to-create-vector-matrix-of-movie-ratings-using-r-project)

However, I am getting an error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.8Gb.

My desktop has 8GB of RAM and I am running ubuntu 11.10 64-bit version. Am I perhaps using the wrong version of R? How would I know, is there a way to determine it while running R? I surely must have the necessary space to allocate this vector.

Comment: `sessionInfo()` will tell you if you are using a 32-bit or a 64-bit version of R.

Comment: alright, thanks. Indeed I am running the 64-bit version, so now I wonder why I might not be able to allocate the vector.

Comment: My understanding is that it doesn't matter how much RAM your system has. If you don't have 2.8Gb of _continuous_ address space, you will see this error.

Comment: does that mean there is nothing I can do to alleviate this? Interestingly enough, I tried doing this in R on my macbook air with 4GB of ram and it doesn't give me the error, however it does hang so maybe it would have eventually returned and complained to me about the lack of memory.

Comment: No, there's (almost) always an answer. Memory issues in R are well-trodden ground. For starters, do a search on SO for "[r] cannot allocate" and do some reading.

Comment: I posted an alternative (more memory efficient?) response to your earlier question, but wonder whether you've worked through your whole analysis with one of the smaller data sets?

Answer (score 9):

The error message means that R needs to allocate **another** 2.8Gb of memory to complete whatever operation you were trying to perform. It doesn't mean it needed to allocate 2.8Gb maximum. Run `top` in a shell whilst you run that R code and watch how R uses up memory until it hist a point where the extra 2.8Gb of address space is not available.

Do you have a large swap space on the box. I can easily see how what you are doing uses all 8Gb of RAM plus all your swap space and so there is no other place for R to get memory space from and thus throws the error.

Perhaps you could try doing the dcast in chunks, or try an alternative approach than using dcast. Post another Q if you want help with that.

Comment: This could be it, I realize I forgot to allocate a swap partition when I installed ubuntu. Let me try doing that and seeing if that resolves this issue.

Comment: @DanQ Hmm, unless you have a lot of time to spare or enjoy twiddling your thumbs, this isn't going to a solution - your disc will just thrash as the OS pushes the data R needs back and forwards between the HD and RAM. You should consider if there are more memory efficient ways of doing what you want.